# Cross origin request blocked port :80

Tags: node.js, nginx, cors

I asked a "friend"(which is not answering my phone btw) to build me an website that it worked fine, until I installed SSL from LetsEncrypt and add cloudflare protection.
I'm keep getting this error, see print screen:
[print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RawwM.png)

I think node.js is trying to connect to port :80 which is a http port not https. Port 443 is used by nginx. (when i turn cloudflare off the website is working again)
From what i read i need a reverse proxy for nodejs but don't know what and where to add.
My site-available/default looks like this:

```
#   listen 80;
#       listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
#   server_name wagthro.com www.wagthro.com;
#       ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/wagthro.com/fullchain.pem; # mana>
#       ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/wagthro.com/privkey.pem; # ma>
#        
#   return 301 https://wagthro.com$request_uri;
#}

server {
    # listen 80 default_server;
    # listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    # root /var/www/html;
    root /var/www/WeAreGoingToHellRo/client/build;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
#   index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name wagthro.com www.wagthro.com;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        if (!-e $request_filename){
                        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.html break;
                }
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/wagthro.com/fullchain.pem; # mana>
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/wagthro.com/privkey.pem; # ma>
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Thank you!

LE:

how do i find the port? i have tried port: 8080, 8000, 3000, 3005, 9229, 5000 and nothing is working.

my nginx looks like this now:

```
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
# https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
#
# In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
# leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
# updated by the nginx packaging team.
#
# This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
# applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#       listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
#   server_name wagthro.com www.wagthro.com;
#       ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/wagthro.com/fullchain.pem; # mana>
#       ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/wagthro.com/privkey.pem; # ma>
#        
#   return 301 https://wagthro.com$request_uri;
#}

server {
    # listen 80 default_server;
    # listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    # root /var/www/html;
    root /var/www/WeAreGoingToHellRo/client/build;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
#   index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name wagthro.com www.wagthro.com;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        if (!-e $request_filename){
                        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.html break;
                }
          location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9229;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
               }

    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/wagthro.com/fullchain.pem; # mana>
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/wagthro.com/privkey.pem; # ma>
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I got this in node server file: server.listen(PORT, () => {
console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error is about CROSS ORIGIN POLICY. Install CORS packge from npm and use it like so in your node server:

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()
app.use(cors())
```

Comment: I get that. But why is trying to connect to port :80? Shouldn't I need a reverse proxy for nodejs, something like this?
```const http = require('http');
http.createServer((req,res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"plain/html"});
  res.end('Node is Running');
}).listen(3000);```

Comment: you are not redirecting connections to your node server. use LOCATION in your NGINX server file. LOCATION should point to your node server run locally.

Comment: So i should add this block
```location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:80;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}```

Comment: i added this. verified with sudo nginx -t and it was ok, restarted successfully nginx now i get  Error 502 error. maybe the node's port is not 80.

Comment: Your Node server should not listen on port 80, your NGINX should. The idea is that your NGINX acts as a proxy between your clients and your Node server, so Node server never gets exposed to the internet, NGINX does. You can run Node on an arbitrary port like 3000 and then set NGINX to redirect connection to this port by setting the LOCATION like "localhost:3000".

Comment: I know that Node server should not listen on port 80, but first you said that "The error is about CROSS ORIGIN POLICY. Install CORS package from npm and use it like so in your node server:"
But I don't know how to change node's port.